# ignore Mapping from DomainModel to ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper

I have 2 fields in DomainModel (CreatedOn,ModifiedOn) which are not in my ViewModel. How can I put ignore on Source fields when mapping from DomainModel to ViewModel. Please fix below code.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<DomainModel, ViewModel>()
                .ForMember(d => d.CreatedOn, opt => opt.Ignore())
               .ForMember(d => d.ModifiedOn, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to specify anything about those fields. Just:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<DomainModel, ViewModel>();
```

If the `CreatedOn` and `ModifiedOn` properties don't exist on your view model when mapping between DM and VM they will be simply ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that AutoMapper will only try to populate those fields in the target.  As long as the target doesn't have fields that happen to be in the source, those fields won't exist in the target after mapping is complete.

However, if the fields did happen to exist in the target, it looks like your syntax is correct (although for consistency with all examples I have seen - you might use dest => dest.CreatedOn instead of d => d.CreatedOn - but I don't think that will break it).

Comment: This code is not working because when I press dot after d properties createdon and modifiedon don't list. This means that d. always displays Target fields. Now all I want is to Ignore values in Source which is DomainModel when mapping from DM to VM. Any solution to that?

Comment: The fields aren't listed by intellisense because they don't exist in the target (your view model).  These fields are already being ignored even though they might exist in the source (your domain model).